# How to create fixed width HTML table in WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create fixed width Html table in webview in android.
i am using the following HTML code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
    table-layout: fixed ; 
    border: 1px solid white ; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body style="background-color:#339933" text=#ffffff >

  <table style="width:25%" ; >
   <tr>
    <td align = "center"; bgcolor = #339933 >17</td>
    <td align = "center"; bgcolor = #339933 >24</td>
    <td align = "center"; bgcolor = #339933 >1</td>
    <td align = "center"; bgcolor = #339933 >8</td>
    <td align = "center"; bgcolor = #339933 >15</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

In java (now working)

```
            WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mgs1);
    String text = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">table, th, td { table-layout: fixed; padding: 2px;  text-align: center; background-color: #339933; border: 2px solid white; border-collapse: collapse; }\"></style></head> <body style=\"text-align:justify; color:#ffffff; margin-right :30px; background-color:#339933;\"> %s </body></Html>";
    String data = "<table style=width: 30%; > <tr><td>17</td> <td>24</td> <td>1</td> <td>8</td> <td>15</td></tr>  </table>";
    view.loadData(String.format(text, data), "text/html", "utf-8");
    view.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);
```

Comment: try **width="25%"** instead of **style="width:25%"**

Comment: my java code is in the question

Comment: i know, and i suggest to change **<table style="width:25%" ; >** to  **<table width="25%">**

Comment: Thanks for you reply. table width="25%" is not working. But i made it work, i edited the above java code which is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Html.fromHtml() to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

For example:

myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("

### Title

Description here

"));

Comment: If you are not sure how to write in Markdown, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting